# Detection of the presence or absence of an element with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, web-scraping

my problem is as follows; First of all, I pull comments from a page, when these comments are long, there is a "see more" button and I press this button. However, the problem starts here, not every page of the page has this button. When it is not found, the programme stops, but if I switch to the other page in my own hand, it continues. I am waiting for your solutions. regards.

```
try:
  button = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.********')
  for button in devamini_gor_button:
     button.click()
     ......
     ....
     ...
except:
  print('Error')
```

Problem Briefly: This button is not found in every comment. Some pages do not have it, so the programme is waiting and I have to manually switch between pages.

First of all, I did research, I found such a function and I thought it returned a bool value (element.is_displayed()) and I assigned it to a value. For example; incoming_value= element.find_element(......).is_displayed()

```
if incoming_value== True:
button = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.********')
  for button in devamini_gor_button:
     button.click()
     ......
     ....
     ...
else:
   comment = driver.find_elements(......);,
```

I did some experiments like this but I got no result.

Comment: an easy way to check for the existence of an element is to use find_elements, and then check the returned webelement array for size.  This method will return a zero size array if not found.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use the "size()" function. I would like to state that I am a computer engineering student and I am doing a new study in this field.

Comment: @PCalkins help me sir.

Comment: If I understood correctly, your problem is that you cannot test a negative. SOME elements have this "see more" button. In order for you to test properly, you must know EXACTLY the conditions that lead to this button appear, replicate the conditions, and then test. You cannot do a proper assertion if you cannot control the conditions. For example, in a controlled situation, if you expect the button to appear, you can write a timeout function that fails the test when the timeout expires. BUT, if the button doesn't show because the comment is not long enough, your test will fail unnecessarily.

Comment: ^^^ Continuing my thoughts from before, say that the button only shows when a comment is longer than 300 characters, you either 1) Know the locations (in the DOM) of these comments (not a good approach) and target them, or 2) Call an API that will allow you to preload a comment of known length to a known location (i.e. first comment on the page) before the test, and then run your test in a controlled way.